# python installed package in site-packages is not accessible from application

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel

I have a python project-A and I have made a whl distribution file from it . i am supposed to use project A in project B. So in project B's virtual envrionment I have installed project A and I can see the project A in env/lib/site-packages and i can also find the dependency in "`pip freeze`".

But from application code of project-B when i am trying to refer code from project A, I am getting `unresolved reference issue`.

this is the response of pip freeze :

```
    (env) D:\python_workspace_31dec\mindsphere-sdk-python-clients>pip freeze
    alabaster==0.7.12
    Babel==2.6.0
    bleach==3.1.0
    certifi==2018.11.29
    chardet==3.0.4
    colorama==0.4.1
    coverage==4.5.1
    docutils==0.14
    filelock==3.0.10
    idna==2.8
    imagesize==1.1.0
    Jinja2==2.10
    MarkupSafe==1.1.0
    mindsphere-core==0.1.0
    packaging==18.0
    pkginfo==1.5.0.1
    pluggy==0.8.1
    py==1.7.0
    Pygments==2.3.1
    pyparsing==2.3.0
    pytz==2018.9
    readme-renderer==24.0
    requests==2.21.0
    requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
    six==1.12.0
    snowballstemmer==1.2.1
    Sphinx==1.8.1
    sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.0
    toml==0.10.0
    tox==3.5.2
    tqdm==4.29.0
    twine==1.12.1
    urllib3==1.24.1
    virtualenv==16.2.0
    webencodings==0.5.1
```

"mindsphere-core==0.1.0" is the project-A here.

```
sys.path gives me the below response:
        ['D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\mindsphere-sdk-python-clients\\timeseries', 'D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\mindsphere-sdk-python-clients\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip', 'D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\mindsphere-sdk-py
    thon-clients\\env\\DLLs', 'D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\mindsphere-sdk-python-clients\\env\\lib', 'D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\mindsphere-sdk-python-clients\\env\\Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\z003wcwj\\AppData\\Local\
    \Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\z003wcwj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs', 'D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\mindsphere-sdk-python-clients\\env', 'D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\
    mindsphere-sdk-python-clients\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

And my current working directory is :

```
D:\\python_workspace_31dec\\
    mindsphere-sdk-python-clients
```

Comment: You are not in the same virtual environment `env`.

Comment: @ParthS007 how ?

Comment: Please add more info of the error you are getting while referencing. I think it might not be related to dependencies.

Comment: @ParthS007 i have observed if I install the package not using virtual env then it works fine. Problem comes with virtual envrionment